# esp32 connection to google spreadsheet using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, esp32, arduino-ide

I'm trying to use POST htttps function and the esp32 seem connected to the script.google.com server but in the process of published data resulting error 401, did I miss some credential for the connection?

Here is my serial monitor result:

[serial monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4hEJ.png)

Here is Arduino IDE code

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <HTTPSRedirect.h>

#include<Wire.h>
#include<LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Enter Google Script Deployment ID:
const char *GScriptId = "";
String gate_number = "Gate1";
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Enter network credentials:
const char* ssid     = "";
const char* password = "";
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Enter command (insert_row or append_row) and your Google Sheets sheet name (default is Sheet1):
String payload_base =  "{\"command\": \"insert_row\", \"sheet_name\": \"credential\", \"values\": ";
String payload = "{insert_row,credential,09090909}";
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Google Sheets setup (do not edit)
const char* host        = "script.google.com";
const int   httpsPort   = 443;
const char* fingerprint = "";
String url = String("/macros/s/") + GScriptId + "/exec";
HTTPSRedirect* client = nullptr;
//------------------------------------------------------------
// Declare variables that will be published to Google Sheets
String student_id;
//------------------------------------------------------------
int blocks[] = {4,5,6,8,9};
#define total_blocks  (sizeof(blocks) / sizeof(blocks[0]))
//------------------------------------------------------------
#define RST_PIN  22  //D3
#define SS_PIN   15 //D4
#define BUZZER   4  //D2
//------------------------------------------------------------
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);
MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;  
MFRC522::StatusCode status;
//------------------------------------------------------------
/* Be aware of Sector Trailer Blocks */
int blockNum = 2;  
/* Create another array to read data from Block */
/* Legthn of buffer should be 2 Bytes more than the size of Block (16 Bytes) */
byte bufferLen = 18;
byte readBlockData[18];
//------------------------------------------------------------

/****************************************************************************************************
 * setup Function
****************************************************************************************************/
void setup() {
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  Serial.begin(115200);        
  delay(10);
  Serial.println('\n');
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  SPI.begin();
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  //initialize lcd screen
  
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  // Connect to WiFi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);             
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(ssid); Serial.println(" ...");
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println('\n');
  Serial.println("WiFi Connected!");
  //Serial.print("IP address:\t");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  // Use HTTPSRedirect class to create a new TLS connection
  client = new HTTPSRedirect(httpsPort);
  client->setInsecure();
  client->setPrintResponseBody(true);
  client->setContentTypeHeader("application/json");
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  
  delay(5000);
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  // Try to connect for a maximum of 5 times
  bool flag = false;
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ 
    int retval = client->connect(host, httpsPort);
    //*************************************************
    if (retval == 1){
      flag = true;
      String msg = "Connected. OK";
      Serial.println(msg);
     
      delay(2000);
      break;
    }
    //*************************************************
    else
      Serial.println("Connection failed. Retrying...");
    //*************************************************
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  if (!flag){
    //____________________________________________
    
    //____________________________________________
    Serial.print("Could not connect to server: ");
    Serial.println(host);
    delay(5000);
    return;
    //____________________________________________
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  delete client;    // delete HTTPSRedirect object
  client = nullptr; // delete HTTPSRedirect object
  //----------------------------------------------------------
}

/****************************************************************************************************
 * loop Function
****************************************************************************************************/
void loop() {
  //Serial.println("[TEST] loop() starts");
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  static bool flag = false;
  if (!flag){
    client = new HTTPSRedirect(httpsPort);
    client->setInsecure();
    flag = true;
    client->setPrintResponseBody(true);
    client->setContentTypeHeader("application/json");
  }
  if (client != nullptr){
    //when below if condition is TRUE then it takes more time then usual, It means the device 
    //is disconnected from the google sheet server and it takes time to connect again
    //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    if (!client->connected()){
      int retval = client->connect(host, httpsPort);
      if (retval != 1){
        Serial.println("Disconnected. Retrying...");
        
        return; //Reset the loop
      }
    }
    //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
  }
  else{Serial.println("Error creating client object!"); Serial.println("else");}
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
 
  //Serial.println("[TEST] Scan Your Tag");
  /* Initialize MFRC522 Module */
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();
  /* Look for new cards */
  /* Reset the loop if no new card is present on RC522 Reader */
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {return;}
  /* Select one of the cards */
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {return;}
  /* Read data from the same block */
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("Reading last data from RFID..."));  
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  String values = "", data;
  /*
  //creating payload - method 1
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  ReadDataFromBlock(blocks[0], readBlockData); //student id
  data = String((char*)readBlockData); data.trim();
  student_id = data;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  ReadDataFromBlock(blocks[1], readBlockData); //first name
  data = String((char*)readBlockData); data.trim();
  first_name = data;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  ReadDataFromBlock(blocks[2], readBlockData); //last name
  data = String((char*)readBlockData); data.trim();
  last_name = data;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  ReadDataFromBlock(blocks[3], readBlockData); //phone number
  data = String((char*)readBlockData); data.trim();
  phone_number = data;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  ReadDataFromBlock(blocks[4], readBlockData); //address
  data = String((char*)readBlockData); data.trim();
  address = data; data = "";
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  values = "\"" + student_id + ",";
  values += first_name + ",";
  values += last_name + ",";
  values += phone_number + ",";
  values += address + "\"}";
  //----------------------------------------------------------------*/
  //creating payload - method 2 - More efficient
  for (byte i = 0; i < total_blocks; i++) {
    ReadDataFromBlock(blocks[i], readBlockData);
    //*************************************************
    if(i == 0){
      data = String((char*)readBlockData);
      data.trim();
      student_id = data;
      values = "\"" + data + ",";
    }
    //*************************************************
    /*else if(i == total_blocks-1){
      data = String((char*)readBlockData);
      data.trim();
      values += data + "\"}";
    }*/
    //*************************************************
    else{
      data = String((char*)readBlockData);
      data.trim();
      values += data + ",";
    }
  }
  values += gate_number + "\"}";
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Create json object string to send to Google Sheets
  // values = "\"" + value0 + "," + value1 + "," + value2 + "\"}"
  payload = payload_base + values;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Publish data to Google Sheets
  Serial.println("Publishing data...");
  Serial.println(payload);
  if(client->POST(url, host, payload)){ 
    // do stuff here if publish was successful
    Serial.println("[OK] Data published.");
   
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  else{
    // do stuff here if publish was not successful
    Serial.println("Error while connecting");
    
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // a delay of several seconds is required before publishing again    
  Serial.println("[TEST] delay(5000)");
  delay(5000);
}


/****************************************************************************************************
 * 
****************************************************************************************************/
/****************************************************************************************************
 * ReadDataFromBlock() function
 ****************************************************************************************************/
void ReadDataFromBlock(int blockNum, byte readBlockData[]) 
{ 
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /* Prepare the ksy for authentication */
  /* All keys are set to FFFFFFFFFFFFh at chip delivery from the factory */
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /* Authenticating the desired data block for Read access using Key A */
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, blockNum, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------s
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK){
     Serial.print("Authentication failed for Read: ");
     Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
     return;
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  else {
    Serial.println("Authentication success");
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /* Reading data from the Block */
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(blockNum, readBlockData, &bufferLen);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print("Reading failed: ");
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  else {
    readBlockData[16] = ' ';
    readBlockData[17] = ' ';
    Serial.println("Block was read successfully");  
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

`

google script code.gs

``

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Zdcq4K1sqtLjSbRouZAgAyhl3ShPjxiHGFbFVb6eGM4');
var timezone = "asia/Kuala Lumpur";
var hours = 0;
var str = "";


function doPost(e) {

  var parsedData;
  var result = {};
  
  try { 
    parsedData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  } 
  catch(f){
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error in parsing request body: " + f.message);
  }
   
  if (parsedData !== undefined){
    var flag = parsedData.format;
    if (flag === undefined){
      flag = 0;
    }
    
    var sheet = SS.getSheetByName(parsedData.sheet_name); // sheet name to publish data to is specified in Arduino code
    var dataArr = parsedData.values.split(","); // creates an array of the values to publish 
         
    var Curr_Date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "MM/dd/yyyy"); // gets the current date
    var Curr_Time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "hh:mm:ss a"); // gets the current time
    //var Curr_Date = new Date(new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() + hours));
    //var Curr_Time = Utilities.formatDate(Curr_Date, timezone, 'HH:mm:ss');

    // coming from Arduino code
    var value0 = dataArr [0];  //Student ID
    var value1 = dataArr [1];  //First Name
    var value2 = dataArr [2];  //Last Name
    var value3 = dataArr [3];  //Phone Number
    var value4 = dataArr [4];  //Address
    var value5 = dataArr [5];  //Gate Number
  
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /* STEP1 - This piece of code searches for the student ID in the attendance sheet. If the student ID is found, 
    it gets the row number of that student ID and retrieves their time-out data. 
    */
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var row_number = 0;
    var time_out = "";
    //for(var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){  // Search last occurrence 
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){  // Search first occurrence of student id
      if(data[i][0] == value0){ //data[i][0] i.e. [0]=Column A, Student_id
        row_number = i+1;
        time_out = data[i][2] //time out [2]=Column C
        
        console.log("row number: "+row_number); //print row number
        console.log("time out: "+time_out); //print row number
        break; //go outside the loop
      }
    }
    /* STEP2 - Next, it checks if the time-out variable is empty. If it is empty, the current time is added to the 
    time-out field and a message is returned to NodeMcu. 
    */
    if(row_number > 0){
      if(time_out === ""){
        sheet.getRange("C"+row_number).setValue(Curr_Time);
        str = "Success"; // string to return back to Arduino serial console
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(str);
      }
    }
    //Otherwise,the attendance is recorded as usual using the code written below
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    
    // read and execute command from the "payload_base" string specified in Arduino code
    switch (parsedData.command) {
      
      case "insert_row":
         
         sheet.insertRows(2); // insert full row directly below header text
         
         sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(value0);     // publish STUDENT ID to cell A2
         sheet.getRange('B2').setValue(Curr_Time);  // publish TIME IN to cell B2
         //sheet.getRange('C2').setValue();         // publish TIME OUT to cell C2
         sheet.getRange('D2').setValue(value5);     // publish GATE NUMBER to cell D2
         sheet.getRange('E2').setValue(Curr_Date);  // publish DATE to cell E2
         sheet.getRange('F2').setValue(value1);     // publish FIRST NAME cell F2
         sheet.getRange('G2').setValue(value2);     // publish LAST NAME cell G2
         sheet.getRange('H2').setValue(value3);     // publish PHONE NUMBER cell H2
         sheet.getRange('I2').setValue(value4);     // publish ADDRESS cell I2
         
         str = "Success"; // string to return back to Arduino serial console
         SpreadsheetApp.flush();
         break;
         
      case "append_row":
         
         var publish_array = new Array(); // create a new array
         
         publish_array [0] = value0;    // publish Student ID to cell A2
         publish_array [1] = Curr_Time; // publish Time In to cell B2
         publish_array [3] = Curr_Date; // publish current date to cell D2
         publish_array [4] = value1;    // publish First Name cell E2
         publish_array [5] = value2;    // publish Last Name cell F2
         
         sheet.appendRow(publish_array); // publish data in publish_array after the last row of data in the sheet
         
         str = "Success"; // string to return back to Arduino serial console
         SpreadsheetApp.flush();
         break;     
    }
    
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(str);
  } // endif (parsedData !== undefined)
  
  else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error! Request body empty or in incorrect format.");
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use POST https req but resulting error on publishing data

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem..The solution was so easy.  It lies in the Deployment of the google script.  Select NEW Deployment (Only Me) and then Anyone.  Get new Deployment ID and paste in arduino code..and it works!  You would think selecting "Only Me" would limit you.  But it has to do with permissions